# Page not found on localhost WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I am working on a WordPress website on localhost using Xampp. Today I changed the site URL and home URL in phpMyAdmin to a host; I plan on transferring my site too, but I ran into some issues so I had to revert it back to localhost.

But now it doesn't work! I have tried 'localhost' and 'localhost/wordpress'. With the latter, I can see my site's header and footer and theme colors etc., but the main frontpage says "not found" and other menu pages also say not found. When I try to access wp-admin, it can't find it either! So I can't even log into the admin panel.

Folders structure:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress
```

Inside the `wordpress` folder, there's .htaccess, index.php, etc. And three folders: wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes.

I don't know why this isn't working any more, I only changed my database's site URL temporarily! Now nothing works and can't access admin panel.

Comment: Check out the database settings maybe you forgot to change password

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that? I did not change my password, the problem is that I can't even access wp-admin so can't input user and password (I remember both) because it says page not found. :S

Comment: I do! How can I solve this issue with it though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure you changed the siteurl and home values in the wp_options table to your localhost like that http://localhost/site
- delete the htaccess file and try to open the site and see
- if you have a security plugin that changes the login url page try to disable it by renaming it's folder name

Comment: Thank you I will try this when I get home. Will let you know if it works!

Comment: Worked!! Thank you so much!!